# Set locale(Language support) in java

Tags: java, locale

The inbuilt java supports only for few languages.I want to use Sinhala language as locale in my jTextPane in java programme.How can i do this ?.Pls help me...

Comment: Do you have right font which supports your language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK **inbuilt Java supports it.** Just create locale: `Locale locale = new Locale("si", "LK");` (si for Sinhala and LK for Sri Lanka). A corresponding bundle could be for example `messages_si_LK.properties`.
You can also use a language code alone. Then: `Locale locale = new Locale("si");` and file `messages_si.properties`. And you have to take care of fonts.

Comment: How can i use this with JTextPane ?

Comment: Look here at setting default locale http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/SetDefLocale.html
Here about fonts http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-appearance/fonts/10font.html (JButton example is similar to JTextPane)

Answer (score 1):

The [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) has extended the Java core libraries' locale support.  They incorporate a much more expansive database of locale info and I believe they cover Sinhalese as the "si" locale.

ICU4J is the acronym for ICU's java specific stuff.  ICU4J = ICU for java.  The ["Why use ICU4J?"](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) part of their FAQ says

> Locale data coverage - much better, many more locales, up-to-date

And it looks like their recent releases have expanded support for Sinhala in particular.  From the [3.6 release notes](http://icu-project.org/download/3.6.html)

> Layout: The font layout engine has support added for Tibetan, Sinhala and Old Hangul.